# Syntax for a logistic multilevel analysis in R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I am looking for advice on what package and syntax to use in R for modelling a logistic multilevel analysis with variables as follows:

- Dependent variable (binary) = 0 or 1
- Independent variable 1 (fixed effect, 2 levels) = A or B
- Independent variable 2 (10 levels, cluster-randomized based on number of subjects, 6 nested within A and 4 nested within B) = A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6 & B1, B2, B3, B4
- Units of measure (rows) = individual subjects

I am interested in extracting an odds ratio with 95% CI for the fixed effect. Any advice or resources are much appreciated, thanks!